# Is it possible to extend Borel's lemma to the case of functional derivatives?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let us think of a collection of tempered distributions $\{ T(x_1, \cdots, x_n)\}_{n=0}^\infty$. Here I will specifically set $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^4$ since I am considering quantum field theory and generating functionals.

My questions are as follows:

Does there exist a (complex-valued) functional $Z[F]$ on the space $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^4)$ of compactly supported smooth functions such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta^n}{\delta F(x_1) \cdots \delta F(x_n)} \frac{Z[F]}{Z[0]} \Biggr \rvert_{F=0}=T(x_1, \cdots, x_n)?
\end{equation}

If the answer is yes, up to what factors is $Z[F]$ unique?

This is clearly generalization of Borel's lemma, but I am not sure if this holds true as well. Could anyone please provide any answer?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: you are starting with a sequence $T_n$, each of which is a tempered distribution on $(\mathbb{R}^4)^n$? And you want to ask whether they appear as a sort of Taylor coefficients for some functional? Don't you need the $T_n$ to be symmetric in its arguments?

Comment: Yes, they must be symmetric. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think it is entirely obvious. Maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07713 is relevant.